# What should be the replication factor of changelog/repartition topics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I know it is possible to configure replication factor these internal topics for the kafka streams, our application uses for normal application topics with replication factor 3 but until now I didn't configured the replication factor for the changelog/repartition topics while my assumption was if one broker dies (or for some reason leader changes) kafka stream application will automatically rebalance to new leader.

Now I am not so sure about a running Kafka Stream application can rebalance to new leader if the internal topics does not use replication factor.

Should we also use replication factor 3 for these internal topics?

Thx for answers....

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you'll want to use the same replication factor of your application topics for your changelog/repartition topics.

You can specify the replication factor your changelog/repartition topics via

```
properties.put(StreamsConfig.REPLICATION_FACTOR_CONFIG, 3)
```

HTH,
Bill