# How to delegate tombstone event to a KTable using selectKey

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have the following kafka stream configuration.

```
StreamBuilder builder = stream("TopicA", Serdes.String(), new 
        SpecificAvroSerde<TestObject>())
    .filter((key, value) -> value!=null)
    .selectKey((key, value) -> value.getSomeProperty())
    .groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.Long(), new 
        SpecificAvroSerde<TestObject>()))
    .reduce((oldValue, newValue) -> newValue), 
        Materialized.as("someStore"));
```

This works as I expect but I can't figure put how I can deal with Tombstone message for TestObject, even I remove

```
.filter((key, value) -> value!=null)
```

I can't figure out how can I deal with 'selectKey' while when the value arrives as null I can't send a tombstone message with 'value.getSomeProperty()' while value will be also null..

How would you deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `transform()` instead of `selectKey()` and store the old `<key,value>` pair in a state store. This way, when `<key,null>` is processed, you can get the previous value from the store, and get the previously extracted new key and send a corresponding tombstone.

However, reduce() cannot process any record with `null` key or `null` value (those would be dropped). Thus, you will need to use a surrogate value instead of `null` to get the record into the `Reduce` function. If the surrogate is received, `Reduce` can return `null`.

Comment: Thx for the answer, I actually don't want to high jack this response for another question, I like to ask you opinion about another question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54979742/what-should-be-the-replication-factor-of-changelog-repartition-topics , is it bad to leave replication factor 1 for changelog/repartition topics for production environment?

Comment: There is already a good answer on this question. I agree with Bill, that you should set replication factor to 3 if a production environment. Note, that for existing topics, you will need to manually reconfigure those topics (cf https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7803)